# Spring WebMVC with embedded Tomcat gives 404 on jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, tomcat

I'm trying to handle JSP in a Spring WebMVC webapp running on embedded Tomcat, however all my requests are returning 404:

```
TRACE 2020-08-23T14:45:50.566 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet(LogFormatUtils.java:88) GET "/", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
TRACE 2020-08-23T14:45:50.568 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory.java:258) Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'websiteController'
TRACE 2020-08-23T14:45:50.569 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:411) Mapped to com.test.web.WebsiteController#homepage()
TRACE 2020-08-23T14:45:50.574 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) Arguments: []
TRACE 2020-08-23T14:45:50.577 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.test.view.SimpleViewResolver(SimpleViewResolver.java:38) No resource found for viewName=index
TRACE 2020-08-23T14:45:50.579 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1839) Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'index'
TRACE 2020-08-23T14:45:50.579 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet(DispatcherServlet.java:1367) Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'index'; URL [/templates/jsp/index.jsp]] 
DEBUG 2020-08-23T14:45:52.089 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView(AbstractView.java:309) View name 'index', model {}
DEBUG 2020-08-23T14:45:52.092 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView(InternalResourceView.java:169) Forwarding to [/templates/jsp/index.jsp]
23-Aug-2020 15:25:31.487 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service JspEngine --> /templates/jsp/index.jsp
23-Aug-2020 15:25:31.487 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service        ServletPath: /templates/jsp/index.jsp
23-Aug-2020 15:25:31.487 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service           PathInfo: null
23-Aug-2020 15:25:31.488 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service           RealPath: null
23-Aug-2020 15:25:31.488 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service         RequestURI: /templates/jsp/index.jsp
23-Aug-2020 15:25:31.488 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service        QueryString: null
DEBUG 2020-08-23T14:45:52.097 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet(FrameworkServlet.java:1131) Completed 404 NOT_FOUND, headers={}
```

Here is how I'm configuring the application:

```java
package com.test.context;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.test")
@EnableWebMvc()
public class ApplicationConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/templates/jsp/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }
}
```

My controller:

```java
package com.test.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class WebsiteController
{
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String homepage()
    {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

I'm configuring Tomcat manually in my main class:

```java
package com.test;

import com.test.context.ApplicationConfiguration;
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.Wrapper;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class ApplicationLauncher
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LifecycleException
    {
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(8080);
        tomcat.getConnector();

        Context ctx = tomcat.addContext("", null);

        // Tomcat JSP Servlet

        Wrapper jspServlet = Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "jsp", new JspServlet());
        jspServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        jspServlet.addMapping("*.jsp");

        // Spring DispatcherServlet

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appCtx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appCtx.register(ApplicationConfiguration.class);
        appCtx.setServletContext(ctx.getServletContext());
        appCtx.registerShutdownHook();
        appCtx.refresh();
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(appCtx);

        Wrapper servletWrapper = Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "dispatcherServlet", dispatcherServlet);
        servletWrapper.setLoadOnStartup(2);
        servletWrapper.addMapping("/");


        tomcat.start();
    }
```

Here's my pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>springjsp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.37</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Seems my requests are hitting the JspServlet okay (as evidenced by the logging output above, and it's hitting the breakpoints in `JspServlet.service()`) but I can't figure out how to configure it to actually work.

The jsp is in `{project dir}/src/main/resources/templates/jsp/`. I've tried providing an absolute path to `internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix()`, but the result is the same.

Comment: The files are located in `src/main/webapp` not from the classpath. Either move your files to `src/main/webapp` or prefix your location with `classpath:`.

Comment: I tried doing `internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/jsp/");`, but it didn't work, and JspServlet logged the RequestUri as `/classpath:/templates...`. Moving the jsp file to `/src/webapp/index.jsp` and setting the prefix to `/` also didn't help.

Comment: Files should be in `src/main/webapp` not `src/webapp`. Classpath is not something that is known to your servlet container. So that might not work (jsp in the classpath is generally a bad idea I mho).

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo. I meant `/src/main/webapp` of course.

Answer (score -1):

try below dependency

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

instead of

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.37</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: The question isn't about Spring Boot.